# Android - NullPointerException calling galleryAddpic from the Android training

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

```
private void galleryAddPic() 
{
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File file;

    try
    {
        file = new File(mCurrentImagePath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }catch(Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Hello everybody,

When I take a picture, I save it a the follow path : /STORAGE/EMULATED/0/HELLO CAMERA 2/JPEG_20151213_171800.JPG

I save its absolute path on mCurrentPhotoPath but when I call the function on the top, I have an exception with a null pointer exception.

I don't understand the reason of this error because I can see the picture is saved at this path. But sometimes it takes a few time to see it appear on the folder...

Thank you for your help

Comment: share your stacktrace please

Comment: I have got this error : E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null. I must add that sometimes, it works and sometimes not and I use a Galaxy S4

Comment: But how about the complete stacktrace?

Comment: @J.Bastin That error is common for Samsung devices, it's pretty innocent and unrelated to the question. Samsung devices can be noisy.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the solution :)

> The default Android camera application returns a non-null intent only when passing back a thumbnail in the returned Intent. If you pass EXTRA_OUTPUT with a URI to write to, it will return a null intent and the picture is in the URI that you passed in.